# CodingBat Java Recursion Slight Conceptual Mistake

Tags: java, recursion

The problem is "given an array of ints, is it possible to divide the ints into two groups, so that the sum of one group is a multiple of 10, and the sum of the other group is odd. Every int must be in one group or the other. Write a recursive helper method that takes whatever arguments you like, and make the initial call to your recursive helper from splitOdd10(). (No loops needed.)     "

I have a correct solution below but all my return values are opposite to the correct ones. The hacky way to fix it was just to switch the boolean at the end but I want to know what mistake I am making conceptually.

```
public  boolean splitOdd10(int[] nums) { 
    if (nums.length==0) return false;

    //Should not have the ! operator
    return (!splitOdd10(nums,0,1));

}
public  Boolean splitOdd10(int[] nums, int lowerBound,int upperBound) {
    int split10Sum=getSum(nums,lowerBound,upperBound);
    int splitOddSum=getSum(nums)-split10Sum;
    if (split10Sum % 10 == 0 && splitOddSum % 2 == 0)   return true;

    if (upperBound < nums.length)   {
        if (splitOdd10(nums,lowerBound,upperBound+1)) return true;
        if (splitOdd10(nums,lowerBound+1,upperBound+1)) return true;
    }
    if (lowerBound < upperBound) 
        if (splitOdd10(nums,lowerBound+1,upperBound)) return true;
    return false;
}


public  int getSum(int[] nums)    {
return getSum(nums,0,nums.length);
}
public  int getSum(int[] nums, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    if (lowerBound == upperBound)   return 0;
return nums[lowerBound]+getSum(nums,lowerBound+1,upperBound);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to note in your answer:

1. `splitOdd10(new int[] {10, 1, 10, })` will return false, and not true.
2. Your `splitOdd10(int[] nums, int lowerBound,int upperBound)` method returns true if it is the current grouping has the `10Sum` divisible by ten, and the `rest` divisible by two, that is if it is even, not odd.

Specifically. for the second point:

```
if (split10Sum % 10 == 0 && splitOddSum % 2 == 0)   return true;
```

Should be

```
if (split10Sum % 10 == 0 && splitOddSum % 2 == 1)   return true;
```

The first point might be OK, depending on what you are trying to solve, that is if you are required to “split” the array into two pieces, then it will work, but might give too many false positives. Specifically, you need to think what should the answers to the following arrays be:

```
[10, 10, 1]
[1, 10, 10]
[1, 10, 2]
[1, 2, 10]
[10, 1, 10]
[10, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely derped and thought odd was % 2 ==0.

Comment: @GeeWay It happens! ;-) If this helped you solve your question, you might want to consider accepting the answer.